# Please help parse this html table using BeautifulSoup and lxml the pythonic way

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table, lxml

I have searched a lot about BeautifulSoup and some suggested lxml as the future of BeautifulSoup while that makes sense, I am having a tough time parsing the following table from a whole list of tables on the webpage.

I am interested in the three columns with varied number of rows depending on the page and the time it was checked. A BeautifulSoup and lxml solution is well appreciated. That way I can ask the admin to install lxml on the dev. machine.

Desired output :

```
Website                    Last Visited          Last Loaded
http://google.com          01/14/2011 
http://stackoverflow.com   01/10/2011
...... more if present
```

Following is a code sample from a messy web page :

```
<table border="2" width="100%">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td width="33%" class="BoldTD">Website</td>
    <td width="33%" class="BoldTD">Last Visited</td>
    <td width="34%" class="BoldTD">Last Loaded</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%">
      <a href="http://google.com"</a>
    </td>
    <td width="33%">01/14/2011
            </td>
    <td width="34%">
            </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"</a>
    </td>
    <td width="33%">01/10/2011
            </td>
    <td width="34%">
            </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: What would you like as a result?  A dictionary entry with the sitename and the dates? 
What is the source of the html? Is it within your control?

Comment: Unfortunately, source of html isn't in my control. A dictionary entry would work, it is just that the no. of rows vary for each page as shown in 'desired output' section. There is no class associated to the table, so if a table has 'website'  in the contents, then we grab that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that uses HTMLParser.  I tried against the contents of [pastebin.com/tu7dfeRJ](http://pastebin.com/tu7dfeRJ). It copes with the meta tag and doctype declaration, both of which foiled the ElementTree version.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyParser(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.line = ""
    self.in_tr = False
    self.in_table = False

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if self.in_table and tag == "tr":
      self.line = ""
      self.in_tr = True
    if tag=='a':
     for attr in attrs:
       if attr[0] == 'href':
         self.line += attr[1] + " "

  def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    if tag == 'tr':
      self.in_tr = False
      if len(self.line):
        print self.line
    elif tag == "table":
      self.in_table = False

  def handle_data(self, data):
    if data == "Website":
      self.in_table = 1
    elif self.in_tr:
      data = data.strip()
      if data:
        self.line += data.strip() + " "

if __name__ == '__main__':
  myp = MyParser()
  myp.feed(open('table.html').read())
```

Hopefully this addresses everything you need and you can accept this as the answer.
Updated as requested.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> table_html = """"
...         <table border="2" width="100%">
...                       <tbody><tr>
...                         <td width="33%" class="BoldTD">Website</td>
...                         <td width="33%" class="BoldTD">Last Visited</td>
...                         <td width="34%" class="BoldTD">Last Loaded</td>
...                       </tr>
...                       <tr>
...                         <td width="33%">
...                           <a href="http://google.com"</a>
...                         </td>
...                         <td width="33%">01/14/2011
...                                 </td>
...                         <td width="34%">
...                                 </td>
...                       </tr>
...                       <tr>
...                         <td width="33%">
...                           <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"</a>
...                         </td>
...                         <td width="33%">01/10/2011
...                                 </td>
...                         <td width="34%">
...                                 </td>
...                       </tr>
...                     </tbody></table>"""
>>> table = html.fromstring(table_html)
>>> for row in table.xpath('//table[@border="2" and @width="100%"]/tbody/tr'):
...     for column in row.xpath('./td[position()=1]/a/@href | ./td[position()>1]/text() | self::node()[position()=1]/td/text()'):
...             print column.strip(),
...     print
... 
Website Last Visited Last Loaded
 http://google.com 01/14/2011 
 http://stackoverflow.com 01/10/2011 
>>>
```

voila;)
of course instead of printing you can add your values to nested lists or dicts;)

Comment: Thanks for the lxml implementation! I am yet to check it since we don't have lxml installed yet on our machines. An admin has to do that, so waiting :( Can we convert this code to BeautifulSoup for a quick check?

Comment: Small typo: change 'table = lxml.fromstring(table_html)' and 'table = html.fromstring(table_html)' and it will run.

Comment: you could use ElementTree etree implementation(which you can be easy installed by easy_install or pip ) to test it, but i'm not sure if it supports full xpath syntax.

Comment: There's an error in the HTML ('<a href="http://google.com"</a>' should be '<a href="http://google.com"></a>' ) but oddly enough, lxml is ok with it but ElementTree is not.

Comment: Installing lxml on centOS is proving to be a challenge :(

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that uses elementtree and the limited XPath it provides:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

doc = ElementTree().parse('table.html')

for t in doc.findall('.//table'):
  # there may be multiple tables, check we have the right one
  if t.find('./tbody/tr/td').text == 'Website':
    for tr in t.findall('./tbody/tr/')[1:]: # skip the header row
      tds = tr.findall('./td')
      print tds[0][0].attrib['href'], tds[1].text.strip(), tds[2].text.strip()
```

Results:

```
http://google.com 01/14/2011
http://stackoverflow.com 01/10/2011
```

Comment: I get this error : doc = ElementTree().parse('test.htm')
  File "/usr/local/Python2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 586, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/local/Python2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1245, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 2, column 61

Comment: It is complaining about your xml.. line 2 column 61. Do you want to post the first lines of that file? Either here or in a pastebin?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like it is looking for strict, well formed text?http://pastebin.com/8BZQyB3b

Comment: Two questions: Are you on Windows? is that the complete file?

Comment: I am on centOS. No it is not the complete file, here it is : http://pastebin.com/tu7dfeRJ

Comment: It seems that ElementTree does not like the DOCTYPE delcaration in your complete HTML file nor does it like the unquoted values for attributes.

Comment: The HTML is not under my control and though I can strip the specific lines, I am working on a more dynamic solution. I am stuck with BeautifulSoup solution, I am unable to parse the td data properly though. I should ask a new question maybe? Thanks for your continued support!

Comment: I added a new answer using HTMLParser.