# BeautifulSoup (Python) and parsing HTML table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table, html-parsing

**##### Update ######** : renderContents() instead of contents[0] did the trick. I will still leave it open if someone can provide a better, elegant solution!

I am trying to parse a number of Web pages for the desired data. The table doesn't have a class/ID tag. So I have to search for 'website' in tr contents.

**Problem at hand :**
Displaying td.contents works fine with just text but not hyperlinks for some reason? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this using bs in Python?

Those suggesting lxml, I have an ongoing thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761158/please-help-parse-this-html-table-using-beautifulsoup-and-lxml-the-pythonic-way) centOS and lxml installation without admin privileges is proving to be a handful at this time. Hence exploring the BeautifulSoup option.

**HTML Sample :**

```
                   <table border="2" width="100%">
                      <tbody><tr>
                        <td width="33%" class="BoldTD">Website</td>
                        <td width="33%" class="BoldTD">Last Visited</td>
                        <td width="34%" class="BoldTD">Last Loaded</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="33%">
                          <a href="http://google.com"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">01/14/2011
                                </td>
                        <td width="34%">
                                </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="33%">
                          stackoverflow.com
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">01/10/2011
                                </td>
                        <td width="34%">
                                </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="33%">
                          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">01/10/2011
                                </td>
                        <td width="34%">
                                </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
```

**Python code so far :**

```
        f1 = open(PATH + "/" + FILE)
        pageSource = f1.read()
        f1.close()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource)
        alltables = soup.findAll( "table", {"border":"2", "width":"100%"} )
        print "Number of tables found : " , len(alltables)

        for table in alltables:
            rows = table.findAll('tr')
            for tr in rows:
                cols = tr.findAll('td')
                for td in cols:
                    print td.contents[0]
```

Comment: Should `<a href="http://google.com"</a>` be `<a href="http://google.com"></a>` (i.e. is it missing a `>`?)

Comment: Updated the HTML with missing >, still no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

pageSource='''...omitted for brevity...'''    

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource)
alltables = soup.findAll( "table", {"border":"2", "width":"100%"} )

results=[]
for table in alltables:
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    lines=[]
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        for td in cols:
            text=td.renderContents().strip('\n')
            lines.append(text)
    text_table='\n'.join(lines)
    if 'Website' in text_table:
        results.append(text_table) 
print "Number of tables found : " , len(results)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

yields

```
Number of tables found :  1
Website
Last Visited
Last Loaded
<a href="http://google.com"></a>
01/14/2011

stackoverflow.com
01/10/2011

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"></a>
01/10/2011
```

Is this close to what you are looking for?
The problem was that `td.contents` returns a list of `NavigableStrings` and soup `tags`. For instance, running `print(td.contents)` might yield

```
['', '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"></a>', '']
```

So picking off the first element of the list makes you miss the `<a>`-tag.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty close but if another table has the same "border", "width" values with unwanted content, it is a problem. How do I limit to only those tables that have 'website' in them (table contents)? Thank you so much btw!

Comment: I've edited the code to show how you might select only those that have the string 'Website' in it. I don't know if 'Website' will always be the first row of the table, so I wrote the code in a more general way -- searching for 'Website' anywhere in the entire table. If you want to search for 'Website' only in the first row, I would process rows[0] separately, test for 'Website', then iterate over the rest of the rows with `for tr in rows[1:]:`.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462061/beautiful-soup-to-parse-url-to-get-another-urls-data/4462877#4462877) . Hope it will help you.

A lay man solution:

```
alltables = soup.findAll( "table", {"border":"2", "width":"100%"} )

t = [x for x in soup.findAll('td')]

[x.renderContents().strip('\n') for x in t]
```

**Output:**

```
['Website',
 'Last Visited',
 'Last Loaded',
 '<a href="http://google.com"></a>',
 '01/14/2011\n                                ',
 '',
 '                          stackoverflow.com\n                        ',
 '01/10/2011\n                                ',
 '',
 '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"></a>',
 '01/10/2011\n                                ',
 '']
```

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am having problems parsing tables and not just anchor tags. In this case, one of the td contents is a URL and I want to grab everything contained in the <td></td> tag.